# Algorithm for convex hull of overlapping rectangles

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull, non-convex

I am looking for the help with finding the most efficient algorithm to solve this problem.
I have a set of overlapping rectangles (possibly unlimited number of them). Every rectangle is defined by four points in X,Y axis.

I would like to get all extreme points of their convex hull.

The problem is that the result should be non-convex polygon as it shows example below.

This example shows three overlapping rectangles:

[image: example]

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask for a convex hull that isn't convex.  I would describe what you want as the outline of a union of rectangles.

Comment: I doubt you will find a solution for a `possibly unlimited` size of input. How is this input even going to be provided? Do you expect an online algorithm that works over a stream of rectangles?

Comment: When I said "possibly unlimited" I meant that sometime the input can be 100 rectangles and sometime 1000 rectangles but always predefined number.